# how to get sub function in php

Tags: php, oop, function, scope

I am working on amazon to vtiger integration, and a code snippet from amazon MWS Client library looks like

```
if ($order->isSetShippingAddress()) {
    echo("                        ShippingAddress\n");
    $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
    if ($shippingAddress->isSetName()) {
        echo("                            Name\n");
        echo("                                " . $shippingAddress->getName() . "\n");
    }
    if ($shippingAddress->isSetAddressLine1()) {
        echo("                            AddressLine1\n");
        echo("                                " . $shippingAddress->getAddressLine1() . "\n");
    }
```

I want to access sub function items like `$shippingAddress->AddressLine1()`

and my code looks like

```
$module          = 'Invoice';
$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
$orderTotal      = $order->getOrderTotal();
$record          = $client->doCreate($module,Array(

                                                  'subject'   => $order->getAmazonOrderId(),
                                                  'customerno'=> $order->getAmazonOrderId(),
                                                  bill_city' => $shippingAddress->getAddressLine1(),
                                                  'bill_state'=> $shippingAddress->getStateOrRegion(),
                                                  'bill_code' => $shippingAddress->getPostalCode(),
```

when I try this, I get error

Fatal error: Call to a member function getAddressLine1() on a non-object

is this a scope error?? how can I use subfunction of $shippingAddress??

help me please

**COMPLETE CODE**

```
function invokeListOrders(MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Interface $service, $request) 
  {
      try {
              $response = $service->listOrders($request);

                if ($response->isSetListOrdersResult()) { 
                    echo("            ListOrdersResult\n");
                    $listOrdersResult = $response->getListOrdersResult();

                    if ($listOrdersResult->isSetOrders()) { 
                        echo("                Orders\n");
                        $orders = $listOrdersResult->getOrders();
                        $orderList = $orders->getOrder();
                        foreach ($orderList as $order) {
                            $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
    include_once('vtwsclib/Vtiger/WSClient.php');                       
$url = 'http://vijayholdings.com/admin';
$client = new Vtiger_WSClient($url);
$login = $client->doLogin('admin', 'MYSECRETKEY');
if(!$login) echo 'Login Failed';                            
            else{   
                    $module = 'Invoice';
                    $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
                     $orderTotal = $order->getOrderTotal();
                    $record = $client->doCreate($module,Array(

          'subject'=>$order->getAmazonOrderId(), 
          'customerno'=>$order->getAmazonOrderId(),
          'invoicestatus'=>'Credit Invoice',/*
          'assigned_user_id'=>'spatel',
          'currency_id'=>'1',
          'conversion_rate'=>'1',  not working*/
          'bill_street'=>$order->getShippingAddress(),/* 
          'bill_city'=>$shippingAddress->getCity(),
          'bill_state'=>$shippingAddress->getStateOrRegion(), 
          'bill_code'=>$shippingAddress->getPostalCode(),
          'bill_country'=>$order->$shippingAddress->getCounty(), */
          'cf_652'=>'Deepdiscounts.co Amazon FBA',/* 
          'cf_653'=>$shippingAddress->getPhone(),
          'cf_656'=>$shippingAddress->getAddressLine2(), */
          'cf_660'=>$order->getShipServiceLevel(),
          'cf_658'=>$order->getSalesChannel(),
          'cf_661'=>$order->getFulfillmentChannel(),
          'cf_663'=>$order->getBuyerName(),       
          'cf_659'=>$order->getBuyerEmail(), 
          'cf_662'=>$order->getPaymentMethod()
          ));
            }
    if($record) {
        $recordid = $client->getRecordId($record['id']);
  echo "The id is ".$recordid;
    }


                 } 
                }
                }

     } catch (MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Exception $ex) {
         echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
         echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
         echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
         echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
         echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
         echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
         echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
     }
```

**OUTPUT OF RAW_DUMP**
HERE IS ONE SALE ORDER FORM THE LIST ON WHICH I AM WORKING

> (1) { ["_fields:protected"]=> array(11) { ["Name"]=> array(2) {
>   ["FieldValue"]=> string(16) "Jason A. Stewart" ["FieldType"]=>
>   string(6) "string" } ["AddressLine1"]=> array(2) { ["FieldValue"]=>
>   string(15) "101 Young Drive" ["FieldType"]=> string(6) "string" }
>   ["AddressLine2"]=> array(2) { ["FieldValue"]=> NULL ["FieldType"]=>
>   string(6) "string" } ["AddressLine3"]=> array(2) { ["FieldValue"]=>
>   NULL ["FieldType"]=> string(6) "string" } ["City"]=> array(2) {
>   ["FieldValue"]=> string(6) "Smyrna" ["FieldType"]=> string(6) "string"
>   } ["County"]=> array(2) { ["FieldValue"]=> NULL ["FieldType"]=>
>   string(6) "string" } ["District"]=> array(2) { ["FieldValue"]=> NULL
>   ["FieldType"]=> string(6) "string" } ["StateOrRegion"]=> array(2) {
>   ["FieldValue"]=> string(2) "TN" ["FieldType"]=> string(6) "string" }
>   ["PostalCode"]=> array(2) { ["FieldValue"]=> string(5) "37167"
>   ["FieldType"]=> string(6) "string" } ["CountryCode"]=> array(2) {
>   ["FieldValue"]=> string(2) "US" ["FieldType"]=> string(6) "string" }
>   ["Phone"]=> array(2) { ["FieldValue"]=> string(10) "6152231070"
>   ["FieldType"]=> string(6) "string" } } }

Comment: Uhm, i am not sure but I think you are missing a quote here: [here]bill_city'

Comment: I have commented the part which is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this means is that your `$shippingAddress` var does not have an object in it.  It is likely that your call to `getShippingAddress()` has failed.

Do a `var_dump($shippingAddress)` to see what's in there.

Comment: @NewBee, Are you sure it's an object, and not an array then?  I can't tell, as you've formatted this terribly in some comment.  Post the raw output of `var_dump()` in your question.

Comment: pasted var_dump result in the question

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error,

```
bill_city' => $shippingAddress->getAddressLine1(),
```

Should be

```
'bill_city' => $shippingAddress->getAddressLine1(),
```

Get a decent IDE, mine picked it up in a few seconds.

[image: IDE Picking up syntax error]